# Ошибка при работе с ListView android

Tags: java, android, listview

Компиляция кода происходит успешно, но при запуске данной активности приложение вылетает и выдает следующую ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pizzaometelly, PID: 6260
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pizzaometelly/com.example.pizzaometelly.BasketPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2563)
        at com.example.pizzaometelly.BasketPage.<init>(BasketPage.java:11)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Java класс:

```
package com.example.pizzaometelly;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


public class BasketPage extends Activity {

    String forexampl [] = new String [] {"Vasya" , "Petya", "Marina", "Pizza"};
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fragment);

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bascket_page);
        //ArrayAdapter<String> backetAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,forexampl);
        //fragmet.setAdapter(backetAdapter);
    }
}
```

активность xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/red_top_background"
        android:fontFamily="@font/main_name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="9sp"
        android:text="@string/OMETELY"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="38sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/basketCapsEn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#8a0606"
        android:fontFamily="@font/test2"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка выглядит так:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Она вызвана тем что вы пытаетесь инициализировать ваш список до того как загружается наполнение экрана, то есть до этого места `setContentView(R.layout.bascket_page);`. Попробуйте переместить инициализацию в функцию `onCreate()`:

```
public class BasketPage extends Activity {
    String forexampl [] = new String [] {"Vasya" , "Petya", "Marina", "Pizza"};

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bascket_page);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fragment);
        //ArrayAdapter<String> backetAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,forexampl);
        //fragmet.setAdapter(backetAdapter);
    }
}
```

и наполнение активности будет инициализировано корректно. Дальше вы сможете использовать данный виджет там где вам нужно. Так же адаптер для вашего списка я бы писал таким образом используя ранее объявленный виджет:

```
listView.setAdapter(backetAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Здесь очень простой список с пояснениями. Вы все поймете.

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/activity_main"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:minWidth="25dp"
 android:minHeight="25dp"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ListView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/listView1"/>

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
//package ru.site.a1;
//здесь должен быть Ваш пакет

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private String[] ara = null;
 private ListView listView1 = null;
 private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //источник данных
   ara = new String[] {"red", "green", "blue"};

   //список
   listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   //адаптер
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, ara);

   //устанавливаем адаптер для списка
   listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
}
```